# Seeking complete example of class based views crud, including template

Tags: python, django, crud, django-class-based-views

Django 1.3 documentation on class based views is seeming like a treasure hunt. How to write the class is clear enough... but what kind of template code matches each generic class? Would someone provide a *complete* example soup to nuts? Here's what I have so far:

### urls.py

```
(r'^brand_create2$',    BrandCreate.as_view()),
```

### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
@login_required
class BrandCreate(CreateView):
    template_name       = 'generic_form_popup.html'
    context_object_name = "brand_thingie"
    #queryset            = models.Brand.objects.all()
    success_url         = '/'
```

### generic_form_popup.html

```
????
```

---

In this case I'm exploring if it is worth learning the new style, given the older style still works:

### urls.py

```
url(r'^brand_create1$', 'coat.views.brand_create'),
```

### views.py

```
class formBrand(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Brand
        exclude = ('')

@login_required
def brand_create(request):

    form = formBrand
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formBrand(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    passed = dict(
        form=form,
        MEDIA_URL  = settings.MEDIA_URL,
        STATIC_URL = settings.STATIC_URL)
    return render_to_response('generic_form_popup.html',
    passed, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### generic_form_popup.html

```
{% extends 'head-plain.html' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block headstuff %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}   
<form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: http://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1266 was helpful to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#createview) **inherits from [ModelFormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin)**, which in turn **inherits from [FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) and [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin)**.

[SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) provides the object template context variable, which is probably not going to be any use in the case of CreateView:

> object: The object that this view is displaying. If context_object_name is specified, that variable will also be set in the context, with the same value as object.

But **[FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) provides the form context variable**:

> form: The form instance that was generated for the view.

Thus, you can **refer to the documentation to [display a form with a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)**:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which means that the very template you posted should **almost** work with the class based view:

```
{% extends 'head-plain.html' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block headstuff %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}   
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>    
{% endblock %}
```

I removed `{{ action }}` because **it is not part of the context**, neither in the old-style view, neither with the class based view, so it doesn't make any sense. You should know that **if action="" then the browser will submit to the current url**. You can force the action to the current url with action="{{ request.path }}" or you can specify another url with the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url).

Suppose apply the best practice of [naming url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), by changing:

```
(r'^brand_create2$',    BrandCreate.as_view()),
```

to:

```
(r'^brand_create2$',    BrandCreate.as_view(), name='band_create'),
```

Then you can use: `action="{% url band_create %}"`.

You can also [customize further](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template):

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.subject.errors }}
        <label for="id_subject">Email subject:</label>
        {{ form.subject }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.message.errors }}
        <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
        {{ form.message }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.sender.errors }}
        <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
        {{ form.sender }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
        <label for="id_cc_myself">CC yourself?</label>
        {{ form.cc_myself }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Of course, **the fields available in the form depend on your Model**.

Comment: I've found with this I don't get access to STATIC_URL.  Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean ? There is no {{ STATIC_URL }} template variable ?

Comment: Correct: there is no {{ STATIC_URL }}

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles